# mongoDB perl '$in' not working

Tags: mongodb, perl

I wrote up a Perl line for querying in [`MongoDB`](http://metacpan.org/module/MongoDB), but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
my $cursor = $collection->find({'genes.symbol'=>{'$in' => [@gene_list]}});
```

The elements (gene symbols) in the `@gene_list` array are separated by spaces (" "). I don't know if this is the issue, because in MongoDB shell, the elements should be separated by a comma. If the `@gene_list` has to be an array with the elements separated by comma, how should I do it?

This @gene_list array include 10 genes:

```
"RAD51C","FRAS1","GRIP1","FREM2","CHMP1A","WRAP53","VAX1","ACTG2","RNASEH2A","CTC1"
```

so, when I do

```
my $count = $myCursor->count;
print $count;
```

I assumed it would print '10' as the count, however, based on my Perl line, it always printed '0', which means the query was not successful.

Comment: We need more information to give an answer to this. Please see [ask]

Comment: One issue I see is that you're using single quotes around $in which prevents interpolation.

Comment: @RonBergin Which is a good thing, because `$in` is a [MongoDB operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in).

Comment: ***"The elements (gene symbols) in the @gene_list array are separated by spaces (" ")"*** No they are not, they are separated by being different array elements.

Comment: What is `$collection`?

Answer (score 1):

It's a shame you're so reluctant to give us any more information about your problem. As it is, all I can do is to offer you an example program which inserts 13 documents into a collection and then uses `find` in the same way as your own code does to retrieve a subset

The only thing I can spot that may be wrong in your own code is that you are using `genes.symbol` as a field name, which is a little bit odd. Are you sure it the *collection* isn't `genes` while the *field* is `symbol`?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use MongoDB;

my $dbh        = MongoDB->connect;
my $collection = $dbh->ns('test.test');

$collection->delete_many({}); # Empty the collection

for my $val ( 'A' .. 'M' ) {
    $collection->insert_one({data => $val});
}

my @filter = qw/ A F N Z /;

my $curs = $collection->find({ data => { '$in' => [ @filter ] } });

my $n = 0;
while ( my $doc = $curs->next ) {
    printf "%2d: %s\n", ++$n, $doc->{data};
}
```

#### output

```
 1: A
 2: F
```